# Redirect from domain to other url and then on landing page

Tags: url, redirect, google-ads-api, affiliate, pay-per-click

I am running google adword campaign for one brand on google search result it will show display url www.mysite.com and when someone hit on the ad then on the url tab first of all it will redirect to some other page then it will show my original url i.e. www.mysite.com Please visit the following link for reference [Example URL](https://youtu.be/4Irc2fr-rS4)

Comment: is this in code you wrote - or are you speaking generally when you browse a certain site?

Comment: @jpmyob i am running google adwords and i want that when user click on my ad it will redirect to a certain url and then from there it will redirect to the final url

Comment: @KirkBeard i am running google adwords and i want that when user click on my ad it will redirect to a certain url and then from there it will redirect to the final url

Comment: Unless you control both URLs, you will not be able to do this. But - for whatever reason you want to do this - window.location.href = '/example.com/some.html'; will redirect, if you put it after some script it'll redirect after your script.

Comment: @jpmyob I am not asking about any coding I am asking about the way how can I do this?

Comment: well, you do it with code...

Answer (score 0):

Rids - If I understand you, you want to set up adwords ad (that you control) to link to your site that you're advertising...then you want to redirect them somewhere else.

You should be able to provide the url in the ad to the first location.

Then you'd have to code something that redirects them to a different url...

There is no way to do a double end point in http protocol. its a request,response. once a user clicks on your ad - they have requested your URL, your server will send a response page, which gets rendered in the browser...

Your server, OR your response page can perform a redirect - but you have to code that. Unless you're using some CMS (content management system) that will 'code' it for you thru an interface...but it's still 'code'

Hope that helps.

Comment: please find the reference through the video in description I have given link.